# How to change Markers with this icon to use Letters in Google Maps using Meteor?

Tags: google-maps, meteor, google-maps-markers, marker

I have markers with this icon but i want to use Letters like a,b,c etc.The icon and Markers code as shown below:

Js Code :

```
var icon = {
      path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeWeight: 1,
      fillOpacity: 1,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      scale: .35
    }

 for(var i = 0 ; i <latLong.length ; i++) {
      late = latLong[i].lat;
      longe = latLong[i].long;
      console.log("i:"+i+" " +late,longe);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(late, longe),
        map: map,
        title:'hi mi lat are ' + late + ' and mi long are ' + longe,
        draggable: false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: icon
      });
    }
```

So please suggest me what to do for this?

Comment: what you have already done? can you please provide us more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First download this [markers set](http://jg.org/mapping/icons.html)

Second create this variable holding the images inside the for or forEach you have to create dynamyc markers.

```
for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) { //where marker array its an array of markers
    var lettersMarker = new google.maps.MarkerImage('marker' + i + '.png');
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: lat[i],lng[i], //or whatever you have.
          map: map,
          icon: image,
      });
```

NOTE: this will work only if you have dynamic markers.

If you don't have for each etc, just create markers like this.

```
var imageMarkerA = new google.maps.MarkerImage('public/markerA.png');
var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: lat[i],lng[i], //or whatever you have.
              map: map,
              icon: imageMarkerA,
          });
var imageMarkerB = new google.maps.MarkerImage('public/markerB.png');
var markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: lat[i],lng[i], //or whatever you have.
              map: map,
              icon: imageMarkerB,
          });
```

And so on...